# Swfupload, change color on hover

Tags: html, css, swfupload

I want to change the text color on hover in a swfupload button.

The color property I put it in 'button_text_style' property, but this widget doesn't seems to have any property to set hover properties.

```
var settings = {
...
    button_text: '<span class="Button">Select photos</span>',
    button_width: "65",
    button_height: "29",
    button_text_style: '.Button {color:#FFF;}',
...
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with

```
buttonStyles = 
                '.Button {color: #FFF' +
                ';font-weight: bold'+ 
                ';font-family: Arial' +
                ';} ' +
                '.Button:hover {color: #000' +
                ';} ';

var settings = {
.....
                button_placeholder_id: "spanButtonPlaceHolder",
                button_text: '<span class="Button">Select photos</span>',
                button_text_style: buttonStyles,
                button_text_left_padding: 12,
                button_text_top_padding: 3,
                button_window_mode: SWFUpload.WINDOW_MODE.TRANSPARENT,
                button_width:  100,
                button_cursor: SWFUpload.CURSOR.HAND,
........
}
```

for some styles (font styles) is necesary use the "button_text_style" property

for other styles the class in the css works fine

but it is essential to add "button_window_mode: SWFUpload.WINDOW_MODE.TRANSPARENT"

Comment: I don't think this :hover code works, despite you saying it does. I don't believe there's anyway to change CSS on hover with SWFUpload. Out of curiosity, I tried your code, and as I thought, it doesn't work. So I'd really like you to explain further. Also, your code is incorrectly assigning colors as 3-character hex codes, when Flash needs the full 6-character hex code. Refer to the Flash 'color' property here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by wrapping SWF object by div and watching for hover event of wrapper:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <object></object>
</div>

$('div.wrapper').hover(function() {
     SWFUpload.setButtonText('<span class="hover">Upload</span>');
}, function() {
     SWFUpload.setButtonText('<span>Upload</span>');
});
```

button_text_style:

```
span {
    color: #000000;
}
span.hover {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use a sprite image and the setButtonImageURL property. You need to create an image that has 4 states (from top to bottom) normal, hover, click and disabled. Below is an example:
http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/formsdemo/XPButtonUploadText_61x22.png

Comment: Thanks Alan, but I need that the css can be changed